# If P(A|B)=1, then is it correct that P(A|B,C)=1 under the assumption that P(B,C)>0?

Tags: probability

If $P(A\mid B)=1$, then what can we say about $P(A\mid B\cap C)$? Is it 1 or not?

The condition says that if B occurs, then A occurs a.s.

Then, if B and C occur, this implies that B has occurred and due to the condition A must occur a.s..

Of course C should be a possible event. This is my intuition. But when I try to prove it by using Bayes' Theorem, I cannot complete the proof:

$P(A\mid B\cap C)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}=\frac{P(C\mid B\cap A)P(A\mid B)P(B)}{P(C\mid B)P(B)}=\frac{P(C\mid B\cap A)}{P(C\mid B)}...$

Then, it seems to me that I am in a cycle.

Comment: Can you explain your intuition for why you suspect it might be true?

Comment: The condition says that if B occurs, then A occurs a.s. Then, if B and C occur, this implies that B has occurred and due to the condition A must occur a.s.. Of course C should be a possible event. This is my intuition.

Comment: Your intuition is solid.  You could use Bayes' Theorem to prove it

Comment: I have tried but it did not work. May be I am missing something very fundamental or simple.

Comment: Post your attempt and people will help you

Comment: You need $P(B\cap C)>0$ but, given that, the answer is yes, it will be $1$, essentially for the reason you give.

Comment: I think you made a mistake: $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(C\mid A\cap B)\;P(A\mid B)\;P(B)$, not $P(C\mid B\cap C)\;P(A\mid B)\;P(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $P(A|B)=1$ implies that $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$. Since $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)$, we conclude $$P(A^c\cap B)=0.$$
Assuming that $P(B\cap C)>0$, then we can say that
$$
P(A|B\cap C)={P(A\cap B\cap C)\over P(B\cap C)}={P(B\cap C)-{P(A^c \cap B \cap C)}\over P(B \cap C)}
$$
Finally, since $A^c\cap B\cap C$ is a subset of an event with a probability of zero, namely $A^c \cap B$, we conclude that $P(A^c \cap B \cap C)=0$ as well, so the above fraction simplifies to $1$.
$\tag*{$\square$}$

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we have a variable $X$ distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. Let $A$ be the event $X\ne\frac12$, $B$ be the event $X\le\frac12$, and $C$ be the event $X\ge\frac12$.

Then $P(A\mid B)=1$ but $P(A\mid B\cap C)=0$.

$B$ and $C$ are a possible events, with non-zero probability; and $B\cap C$ is also a possible event (albeit with zero probability). But $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ is not equal to $1$. So it's not surprising that you can't prove that it is. You also need that the probability of $B\cap C$ is non-zero.

Comment: $B \cap C$ has zero probability

Comment: @Yalikesifulei: that does not make it an impossible event. For any $a\in[0,1]$, the probability that $X=a$ is zero; but $X$ must take _some_ value in $[0,1]$, even though the probability of its taking that value is zero. $B\cap C$ is the event $X=\frac12$, which has zero probability but is not impossible.

Comment: But @Yalikesifulei, if $B\cap C$ has zero probability, then isn't $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ is undefined?

Comment: @bc78: No. Just look at my example!

Comment: What I am trying to say is this by definition to be able to talk about $P(A\mid B)$, $P(B)$ must be strictly positive.

Comment: @bc78 That is indeed inescapable if we define $P(A|B)$ as the fraction $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. But we can alternatively define $P(A\mid B)$ as the element of $[0,1]$ with the special property that $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$. This element is unique if $P(B)\neq0$ and equals the fraction. If $P(B)=0$ every value of $[0,1]$ can be used for $P(A|B)$ and we are free to choose a *suitable* value. For instance $P(X=c\mid X=c)=1$ and $P(X=c+1\mid X=c)=0$ where $X$ has continuous distribution (so that $P(X=c)=0$).

Comment: @drhab: no, we are not free to choose any value in $[0,1]$. In my example, $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ is well-defined and has the value $0$. In words, it is simply the probability that $X\ne\frac12$ given that $X=\frac12$. I think you will agree that this can't be anything but $0$.

Comment: In words that is obvious, but how about the applied *definition* in maths? What does it look like? As long as there isn't such definition the equality $P(A\mid A)=1$ is not more than a matter of intuition in the case where $P(A)=0$.

Comment: BTW: I am the upvoter of your (exposing) answer. In great lines I agree with you.

Comment: @drhab: good to know! But I must admit that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) agreees with _you_: it says that $P(A\mid B)$ is _defined_ as $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$, so it is undefined if $P(B)=0$. In general, I accept this; but in particular cases, such as my example, we can evaluate it.

Comment: Yes, and what you call "evaluate" is what I call "choosing a suitable value". We are on the same line.

Comment: (-1) for lack of rigor, and being potentially confusing to beginners. The only ways to rigorously condition on a zero-probability event is to use regular conditional probabilities, else you can run into Borel's paradox.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: what do you mean by "regular conditional probabilities"?

Comment: @TonyK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability Essentially, it is a way to make sense of $P(E\mid X=a)$, where $X$ is a random variable for which $P(X=a)=0$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: I'm learning a lot today! I never heard of Radon spaces before.